# Finding the first 100 prime numbers using array (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to show the first 100 prime numbers using array in java, it works with no problem, but the output shows zero before each number:
- What i want:
2 3 5 11 13 17....
- The output i'm getting:
2 03 05 011 013 017....
Do anyone know how to remove the zero digit from the numbers in the output?
Thank you

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

     class ttar

      {  



       public static void main(String args[])

         {
            int[] array = new int[542];
            int m;

            int primumnum;
            String r = "";


            for (m=0; m<=542; m++)
            {
                int counter = 0;

                for(primumnum=m; primumnum>=1; primumnum--)
                {
                    if(m % primumnum == 0)
                    {
                        counter = counter + 1;
                    }
                }
                if(counter == 2)
                {
                    r = r + m + " ";
                    r+= array[m];

                }

            }
             System.out.println("These are the first 100 prime numbers");
             System.out.println(r);

             }
             }
```

Comment: put it easily in a separate int array

Comment: if you already know how to use += operator, why don't you use it here `r = r + m + " ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are doing r+=array[m] in your code.As sugessted by @Henry this line is causing the problem if you will comment this line in your code you will get the desired result.

```
int[] array = new int[542];
    int m;

    int primumnum;
    String r = "";


    for (m=0; m<=542; m++)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        for(primumnum=m; primumnum>=1; primumnum--)
        {
            if(m % primumnum == 0)
            {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
        if(counter == 2)
        {
            r = r + m + " ";
            //r+= array[m];

        }

    }
```

or to get the prime number you can also do as below,

```
class GeneratePrime{
 public static boolean isPrime(int x)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(x); i++) {
            if (x % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

public static void main(String args[]){
    int currentNumber = 2;
    int primesFound = 0;

    while (primesFound < 100) {
        if (isPrime(currentNumber)) {
            primesFound++;

            System.out.print (currentNumber + " ");
            if (primesFound % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        currentNumber++;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The 0 comes from this line:

```
r+= array[m];
```

You never assign any values to the array so all elements are 0.

Why do you have the array in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually, i'm new to array in java, i want to use it to get the first 100 prime numbers.

Comment: Yes, but you don't use it. Remove all references to the array and your program will do what you want (there is still room for improvement though)